# Manifold of mappings between $M$ and $N$, with non-compact source $M$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, sg.symplectic-geometry, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, floer-homology

**EDIT:** Let $M$ and $N$ are two smooth manifold and suppose $N$ is compact but $M$ is not necessarily compact. For my purpose, I just need to consider the case $M=\mathbb R \times S^1$ or $\mathbb R \times [0,1]$.

Thanks to David's comments that help me a lot, the problem I really concern is just the following.

**Question:**

1. Now that we know if $M$ is non-compact then $C^\infty(M,N)$ is
   modeled on spaces $C^\infty_c(M,N)$. Since we know
   $W^{k,p}_0(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C^\infty_c(\Omega) $ in
   $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ for $\Omega\subset \mathbb R$, in analogy, can we
   say $W^{k,p}(M,N)$ is modeled on spaces $W^{k,p}_0(M,f^*TN)$? Any reference?
2. Can we consider $W^{k,p}_0(M,f^*TN)$ as a completion (in some
   sense?) of $C^\infty_c(M,f^*TN)$, the spaces of smooth sections with compact support of pullback bundles along $f:M\to N$?

---

Previous post:

**(1)** Can we define $W^{1,p}_0(M,N)$ 
 in a similar manner that $W^{1,p}_0(\mathbb R)$ is defined by the completions of $C^\infty_0$ or $C^\infty_c$?

- For example, Floer in [his paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1002/cpa.3160410603/asset/3160410603_ftp.pdf?v=1&t=j5095eur&s=9385885258b1b9f84fc0142d956b95fa460d1a2e) (see Definition 2.1) actually
  discusses (roughly) $\mathcal W:=W_{loc}^{k,p}(\mathbb R \times
     [0,1], N)$ with a topology given by open sets as follows: $ \mathcal
     O_{u,\rho,\epsilon} =\{ v\in \mathcal W \mid v= \exp_u \xi
     ~\text{on}~ [-\rho,\rho]\times[0,1], ~\text{and}~ ||\xi||_{W^{k,p}}
     <\epsilon  \} $ On the other hand, Audin and Damian in [their
  book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781447154952) (see Definition 8.2.2) consider Banach manifolds $\widetilde
     {\mathcal W} =W^{k,p}(\mathbb R \times [0,1], N)$ (actually $[0,1]$
  should be replaced by $S^1$) in a quite different manner. Here open
  sets are the space of maps of the form $v=\exp_u \xi$ where $\xi \in
     W^{k,p}(\mathbb R \times [0,1], N)\equiv W_0^{k,p}(\mathbb R \times
     [0,1], N)$ and where $u$ is smooth and converges in some decay at the
  infinity.

  Heuristically, $\mathcal W$ is like the completion of $C_c^\infty$
  while $\widetilde {\mathcal W}$ is like that of $C_0^\infty$.

**(2)** Is $\mathcal W$ the same as $\widetilde{\mathcal W}$? Which one could be a better candidate for the definition of $W^{k,p}_0(M,N)$? Are they both Banach manifolds as in the case $M$ is compact?

- Recently I notice that when considering (infinite-dimensional)
  manifolds of mapping, say $C^\infty(M,N)$, we usually require $M$ to
  be compact. (See Section 4.2 of this paper: [The inverse function
  theorem of Nash and Moser](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183549049)). Notice that as long as the domain $M$
  is compact, the questions (1), (2) and (3) become trivial.

**(3)** In general, if $M$ is non-compact, then is $C^\infty(M,N)$ still a Frechet manifold as in the case $M$ is compact?

---

Comment: $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R})$ is not the completion of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. It is the completion of $W^{1,p} \cap C^\infty$.

Comment: I see, I have edited.

Comment: A common approach is to embed $N$ into a high dimensional vector space and use the Banach submanifold of vector-valued functions with the desired regularity, whose image lies almost everywhere in $N$.

Comment: Can you explain or give a source to your assertion that $W^{1, p} (M, N)$ is a Banach manifold? Is it true for every $p \ge 1$?

Comment: @JeanVanSchaftingen  I read this in the case of M = S^2 from Mcduff-Salamon's book on J holomorphic curves

Comment: If M is non-compact, $C^\infty(M,N)$ is locally convex, but not necessarily complete, as the model spaces are of compactly supported smooth sections.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thank you for your comment. This is really helpful. I just refer to Kriegl-Michor's book (42.1) which states that if $M$ is non-compact then$C^\infty(M,N)$  is in general modeled on spaces $C^\infty_c(M, f^*TM)$ of smooth sections with compact support of pullback bundles along $f:M \to N$. But, I feel pretty confused that why we have to restricts to sections with compact supports here?

Comment: @Hang it's better to see Michor's book _Manifolds of differentiable mappings_, available from his website. There are more modern treatments, eg by Alexander Schmeding.

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09127

Comment: In answer to your question, without compact support one cannot define the relevant supremum seminorms on partial derivatives. Of course, the function spaces themselves contain all smooth functions.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thank you. Now that we know if $M$ is non-compact then $C^\infty(M,N)$ is modeled on spaces $C^\infty_c(M,N)$. But as I study symplectic geometry, what I really concern is $W^{1,p}(M,N)$ for $M$ non-compact. We know $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C^\infty_c(\Omega) $ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for $\Omega\subset \mathbb R$, in analogy, can we say $W^{1,p}(M,N)$ is modeled on spaces $W^{1,p}_0(M,f^*TN)$(which actually I don't know how to define properly) ?

Comment: @DavidRoberts  Moreover, can we consider $W^{k,p}_0(M,f^*TN)$ as a completion (in some sense?) of $C^\infty_c(M,f^*TN)$?

Comment: @JeanVanSchaftingen I think $W^{1,p}(M,N)$ is a Banach manifold if $p>{\rm dim}\, M$ but if $p<{\rm dim}\, M$, then it is not.

Comment: @JeanVanSchaftingen Plese check my answer and edit it if necessary.

Comment: Your revised question 2 is related to https://mathoverflow.net/q/126419/3948

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $M$ and $N$ be Riemannian manifolds.
In general, the space of Sobolev mappings $W^{k,p}(M,N)$ should not be defined as a completion of smooth mappings even if $k=1$ and manifolds are compact. The common definition (at least if $N$ is compact) is as follows. Take an isometric embedding of $N$ into a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R^\nu}$ and then define:
$$
W^{k,p}(M,N)=\{ f\in W^{m,p}(M,\mathbb{R}^\nu):\, f(x)\in N \text{ a.e.} \}.
$$
This space is equipped with the metric inherited from the Sobolev norm and in general smooth mappings are not dense [1]. There are some problems when $N$ is not compact. You can find more papers about higher order Sobolev mappings between manifolds, including the case of non-compact target, at the homepage of 
[Van Schaftingen](https://perso.uclouvain.be/jean.vanschaftingen/).

[1] P. Bousquet, A. C. Ponce, J. Van Schaftingen, Strong density for higher order Sobolev spaces into compact manifolds. *J. Eur. Math. Soc. (JEMS)* 17 (2015), no. 4, 763–817.

Answer (score -1):

Too long for a comment: If $M$ is a manifold, you have no volume form, and you cannot give a meaning to integrability of a function. To express integrability, you have to use densities, which are smooth sections of the fiber bundle of densities over the manifold $M$. Note that you don't have this difficulty with your example, since you have then  the form $dx\wedge d\theta$ on $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R
/2π\mathbb Z$.

Comment: The issue is not with $M$, where you can simply restrict to functions that are period in the second input. The issue is how to define Sobolev spaces of maps into a manifold $N$.